# VHDL Order of options in case statement

Tags: case, vhdl

I am writing a FSM in VHDL for a basic CPU control unit. In a process I use case statement to decode instruction code. My question is, does the order of the when "..." => statements matter/change anything, or will the inferred "circuit" be the same? I suspect it will, but I want to be sure.

I'd rather have the cases in order that is easy to orientate in, not ordered by value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the `when "..." =>` statements cannot possibly matter/change anything in simulation or synthesis because in VHDL they *must* be mutually exclusive.

Comment: In addition to this short and precise answer: That's the big difference to a `if-elsif-...-elsif-else`-chain, which creates a priority.

Comment: I's  still possible to create a priority encoder using a matching case statement . See IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.9 Case statement, starting at paragraphs 6 and depending on the predefined operators "?=" (para. 10). See the "?=" Right operand table in 9.2.3 Relational operators, para. 12. (Whether anyone's synthesis tool will accept it is another question). A case statement can be devolved into if then elsif..., there's simply added rules on the choices (if statement conditions).  Sorry to throw a monkey wrench in 'short and precise', add the word 'ordinary' in front of case statement.

Comment: @user1155120 I must admit I've learnt something there - I didn't know about `case?`. Thank you. However, from what I can find out, the branches still have to be mutually exclusive. IEEE Std 1076-2008 still says "NOTE 1—The execution of a case statement chooses one and only one alternative, since the choices are exhaustive and
mutually exclusive."

Comment: **Example 5.7** *Priority arbiter using don't care matching*,  Page 149, *VHDL-2008 Just the New Stuff*, Peter J. Ashenden and Jim Lewis.  There are two errors in the text narrative on Page 150.  There's also matching selected assignment. And these are terribly difficult to get right in a VHDL tool, an example where the standard should provide test cases. The original comment was in response to Paebbels comment claiming priority was the domain of if statements.

Answer (score 1):

The order does not have any effect.

```
case State is
  when A => ...
  when B => ...
end case;
```

is identical to

```
case State is
  when B => ...
  when A => ...
end case;
```

I suppose some synthesis tools could produce different state encoding based on the order, but this should not be something that you should have to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in your order because the synthesis tool will collect all branches of case statement and put them in one big multiplexer. The multiplexer will evaluate on your different branch conditions (obviously your inputs).

Don't forget `when others =>` statement ;)

More information about "case statement":
http://www.vhdl-online.de/courses/system_design/vhdl_language_and_syntax/sequential_statements/case_statement